# Prevent User from running applications on windows CE

Tags: .net, windows-ce, opennetcf

we have windows ce 5.0 devices and want to lock them down ie. only allow the user to run our application that is installed on the device. We are thinking perhaps there is someway we can turn this lock-down mode off an on.

For example we don't want users to be able to run Internet Explorer or Windows Media Player etc.

Perhaps there are some libraries out there that can assist with this? I've checked out the Opennetcf library but can't get any direction.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: http://www.soti.net/Mobicontrol/Default.aspx

Comment: @Musi I think your platform builder option was good as well.  Why delete?

Comment: @Will: as solutions go, it's probably pretty high on the degree-of-difficulty-and-hit-to-the-wallet scale, but OK.

Comment: And if you don't have a BSP it's a non-starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I really recommend this (since it's rather difficult and would cost $$$), but the ideal way to do this is to use [Platform Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448756.aspx) to basically make your own custom version of the OS.

**Update:**  An alternative hack suggestion would be to have your app use the `FindWindow` and `SendMessage` API functions to periodically locate running instances of the apps you want to deny access to and shut them down programmatically.  This isn't perfect, obviously, as it won't work if your app is not running.

Answer (score 2):

Your first stop should be to check with the OEM.  See if they can provide you a custom OS build that omits the features you don't want.  Now if you're using something like Intermec or Motorola handhelds, then you're going to be out of luck, as they don't provide custom OS builds, nor do you get a BSP so doing it yourself is not an option.

It's possible that you can write a Shell replacement app (must be done in C) and modify the registry to load your app instead of explorer.exe.  That would provide a much greater ability to limit what the user can do, but even in that case things like Control Panel applets cannot be individually removed - it becomes all or nothing (or create your own CPL infrastructure).

In short, it really, really depends on what your actual target hardware is.

Comment: The OEM won't provide us with a custom build - We are using Motorola/Symbol devices. There are only a handful of apps we want to prevent user from launching (Internet Explorer; Windows Media Player, Date Time Applet). There is some registry hack?